# AggregatorV3Interface address for ETH/USD for sepolia

Tags: solidity, remix, chainlink

In the example on chain.link for [AggregatorV3Interface](https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/price-feeds/#solidity) for solidity,

```
/**
 * Network: Sepolia
 * Aggregator: BTC/USD
 * Address: 0x1b44F3514812d835EB1BDB0acB33d3fA3351Ee43
 */
```

Where do you get the address for the ETH/USD instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get them on chain-link official docs:
https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/price-feeds/addresses/#Sepolia%20Testnet

It's 0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306